# example for caching cloud function for firebase requests and only re cache after a successful edit to the profile

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

In my app, Users profiles are open to the public and only updated by the profile owner.

The profile URL is `example.com/profile?user=@user.me`

And based on the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions. I can cache the response JSON of the function, in this case, the public profile. Which will save me a lot of at cloud functions  executions and Firebase database bandwidth

And when the user updates his profile, I want to re cache the profile in the CDN.

I think that can be done by making the user re-request his public profile, with `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the request header, after a successful update of his profile.

And when a user visits that same profile afterward he shall see the new version.

Is that possible ?? or that's not how `Cache-Control` shall be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The integration between Cloud Functions, Firebase Hosting and its CDN is currently a purely time-to-live based cache. When you set a cache-header in your Cloud Functions, the CDN puts your response in its edge caches for the time period you indicate. Once it expires, the CDN edges will stop serving the content from the cache and request a fresh copy from the server when a user on that edge requests it.

We know that having an API to tell the CDN to refresh this content would allow for many additional use-cases. But this is currently not in the scope of Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Is using the CDN caching feature available outside cloud functions for firebase ?? If I set a small instance running nodejs can I cache the results on firebase hosting for x minutes for example ?? sorry if the question is a bit out of scope.

Comment: I don't think there is any API to access Firebase Hosting outside of Cloud Functions.

Comment: @HadyRashwan Firebase does support now support Cloud Run integration with Firebase Hosting - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Are CF/CR generated files cached on FB Hosting flushed with a new deployment of said CF/CR service?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's probably worth trying.

Comment: @jthegedus Did it flush with a new deployment?

Comment: @Ayyappa I don't believe so, but it is another way than Cloud Functions to produce data to be cached.

Comment: Will this work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52844803/413306 ?