# Firebase hosting with cloud functions - how to purge/refresh CDN cache?

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions, cdn, firebase-hosting

I'm following the instructions from this video and so far things are working perfectly right up to the point where I need to purge the CDN of old HTML:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_2CJs_VZk4

So far I've created a static HTML page using Firebase Cloud Functions, and it is stored on Firebase Cloud Storage. Whenever data from my Firebase Database is updated, a new and updated static HTML page is rendered and is saved to the Cloud Storage.

Firebase Hosting serves that static HTML page, and it is stored on the CDN.
As per the above video, I've set a long refresh time for the CDN because I only want it to update when I make a change to the data in Firebase Database (no refreshing the CDN if no change has been made)

For this to work, when the page is updated, the old HTML page stored on the CDN must be purged and replaced with the new HTML page.

The video at time 33:19 suggests the following code:

```
const purgeUrl = `${ORIGIN}/${path}`;
await request(purgeUrl, { method: "PURGE" });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I can see that the page has updated on Cloud Storage, but when I refresh the URL the new HTML page is not displayed.
The only way I can show the new HTML is by re-deploying the firebase code again (terminal - firebase deploy).

Here is my code (in node.js):

```
const ORIGIN = "examplesite-30ccf.firebaseapp.com/";

function getFacts(){
  return database.ref('/web app/test').once('value').then(snap =>snap.val());
}

exports.updateHomePage = functions.database.ref('/web app/test')
.onWrite((snap, context) => {

  return getFacts()
  .then(result1 => {
    console.log("result1", result1);
      return bucket
      .file('public_html/index.html')
      .save(HomePage(result1), {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: {
          contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
          cacheControl: "max-age=300, s-maxage=31536000" // indef CDN cache since we purge manually
        }
      }); 
  }).then(doNotUse => {

    const purgeUrl = `${ORIGIN}`;
    console.log("purged URL", purgeUrl);
    return request(purgeUrl, { method: "PURGE" });
}).catch(error => {
      // Handle errors of asyncFunc1() and asyncFunc2()
  });

});`
```

There is no crash or exceptions in the Firebase Functions logs. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I inadvertently found the answer while trying to fix another issue.

You need to be on a paid Firebase plan to make external API calls:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

So the PURGE method does work so long as you have upgraded you plan.
Here is the code that allows you to purge the CDN (Node.js in Typescript):

```
import * as request from "request-promise";

const purgeUrl = `examplesite.com`;
await request(purgeUrl, { method: "PURGE" });
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it with cloud functions?

Comment: Yes it is Ayyappa

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me give a try again. I was not able to get it right earlier.

Comment: Is this still functional? Are you executing this from the functions?

Comment: 06 / 29 / 2020 still works, gotta enable pay as you go plan and it triggers. You should also see the billing error in the functions logs in firebase. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Is there any authentication needed to this? How does it work? Is there any documentation? Also, does it clear all `Vary` header variations? You'll get one cache per `Use-Agent` if you set the `Vary: User-Agent` header

Answer (score 7):

Simply execute a curl command:

`curl -X PURGE https://yoursite.com/path`

Comment: Can this be used in production from a function code?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions presented in the previous answers do work (once you figure one thing out):

1. When you run Firebase Hosting to redirect to the function, you have to point the `PURGE` request at the hosting domain, not the function domain  (took me a while to figure this out).
2. You can not have your domain also setup with CloudFlare (they do not forward `PURGE` requests).
3. And if you do have your domain setup with Cloudflare then you have to do something like this:

You can create a `PURGE` request pointed at the `you-project.web.app/whatever-path/here` url and the Header `Host: your-domain.com`

This will then respond with:

```json
{
    "status": "ok",
    "id": "13932-1644936633-2"
}
```

Here is my code example using `[got][1]`:

```js
const firebaseHostingUrl = 'https://you-project.web.app'
const customHostingUrl = 'https://your-domain.com'

async function handleCachePurge(context) {
  const functionUrl = `${firebaseHostingUrl}/${context.request.path}`
  try {
    gotResponse = await got(functionUrl, {
      method: 'PURGE',
      headers: {
        Host: customHostingUrl,
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

The CURL version of this would be:

```
curl --request PURGE \
  --url https://you-project.web.app/whatever-path/here \
  --header 'Host: your-domain.com'
```

Comment: Super helpful! Particularly the point about using web.app to get around CloudFlare

Answer (score 0):

I have a project which uses functions and hosting feature of Firebase.

After update of function I have deployed it but I met cache problem.

In my case only re-deploying files to **hosting** helped.