# Data driven cache on Firebase with Cloud Functions SSR + Hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

Is it possible (and reliable?) to use *Firebase Cloud Function* for **S**erver **S**ide **R**endering AND store the rendered file on *Firebase Hosting*?

- Cloud functions SSR are getting triggered on data update, not visits
- Using CDN for the whole page (faster, no cloud function cold start)
- Can be really convenient in some situation (lot of read, few data updates)

SSR tutorials for firebase show how to create dynamic page with time-driven cache (not data-driven) and only use Hosting for static asset being added **before** the deployment.

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200')
```

Plus i can't find any api to send rendered file to Hosting from a cloud function..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data update re-rendering of SSR pages is not supported in Firebase. It may become achievable in the future if Firebase had an API for Firebase Hosting, but as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45255829/7911479 it's not on their radar.